# how to fetch data from json file using vite reactjs

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch, vite

#### Note

vitejs build tool used to create reactjs-app.

### Question

I can read **data.json** in development server but i can't read **data.json** from production how can i fix this.

### [File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StWgy.png)

code for fetching data.json

```
    fetch('data/data.json').then(res => res.json()).then(d => {
        setNet({...net, isLoading: !net.isLoading})
        setData(d);
    }).catch(err => setNet({...net, msg: <p>Some thing went <span className="err__wrong">wrong</span> please try again after some time....</p>}))
  }, [])
```

if i build reactjs using `npm run build` in dist file there is no **data.json** file.

anyone can fix this?

[Here is the project repo](https://github.com/hex909/job-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a public folder at root level and put your json file there so after build it will be inside dist folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).