# Relative path dosent work when trying to load json from a local file

Tags: javascript, json

```
const exploreRivers = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('../assets/stationData.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));
  },[])
```

I am fetching the local json data like showed above, the json data format is like this:

```
"[\n  {\n    \"stationName\": \"Femsj\\u00f8\",\n    \"stationId\": \"1.15.0\",\n    \"river\": \"Haldenvassdraget\",\n    \"kommune\": \"Halden\",\n    \"kommuneNumber\": \"3001\",\n    \"fylke\": \"Viken\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"stationName\": \"Lierelv\",\n    \"stationId\": \"1.200.0\",\n    \"river\": \"Haldenvassdraget\",\n    \"kommune\": \"Aurskog-H\\u00f8land\",\n    \"kommuneNumber\": \"3026\",\n    \"fylke\": \"Viken\"\n  },\n  {\n
```

[My file structure looks like this: image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvkNF.png).

Json data is inside stationData.json

In the error message it looked like my program is trying to fetch from a full url, error message follows as link right under :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBGds.png) error message

I tried to change the path from relative to absolute, but still no luck.

Comment: Please don't post images of errors; post the **actual text** of the error(s), in full.

Answer (score 2):

I would add it to public folder. Because when your app builds it takes the contents of this folder and inject those files into the dist folder from which app boots (and it's your base relative path). Just a guess from previous experiences so check it and let us know the outcome.

Also there is base path in vite config. Some more info about this is here: [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744253/vite-build-always-using-static-paths). You can modify the base paths for your app. So I hope that now you can google it better with that knowledge.

Also similar problem is here: [vite doesn't add json file after build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115812/how-to-fetch-data-from-json-file-using-vite-reactjs)